# How to calculate how many polygons I can put inside a polygon?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I usually use QGIS.
I explain my problem with an example:
there is a forest (irregular geometry1) and one tree (geometry2).
I want to know the maximum number of trees that the forest can contain. Furthermore, I want a shapefile output of the best disposition of these trees inside the forest.[image]

Comment: Nice problem....

Comment: I don't know how I would even start. Sounds like a Maters degree problem/algorithm.

Comment: If you can gain access to a free trial of ArcGIS (or download R which is free), the [Geospatial Modelling Environment](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gencirclesinpolys.htm) software has a `gencirclesinpolys (Generate Circles In Polygons)` tool which could be useful.

Comment: You're looking for a tool to solve [Packing problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems) but I'm not aware of any for QGIS

Comment: @Joseph I used the tool Geospatial Modelling Environment, it works. Unfortunately the tool generates a regular arrangement of circles (or hexagon) within the bounds of polygons, this implies that the output shape doesn't show (necessarily) the best disposition of the features, I mean the maximum number possible of it.

Comment: @underdark can you suggest me another way to solve this issue using another software that is not qgis?
thanks.

Comment: @Joseph Could you suggest me a tool like  GME (or the better way) to fit inside the polygon rectangle or rhombus?
or how to build a centroids  grid that could be the base to insert the geometries (rectangle or rhombus)?
thanks

Answer (score 6):

Interesting problem!

I've done a similar thing with irregular polygons (in this case, buildings were packed so as not to overlap)

[image]

Used postgresql and postgis, and python. Rough algorithm was

- Find random point in polygon's bounding box (ST_Envelope)
- If point outside polygon, go back one step
- Make a geometry for the tree centred this random point
- If that overlaps any existing placed tree (ST_Overlaps), go back to start
- Add tree at point
- Go back to start

I can't guarantee this will give the global optimum, you'd need a 'circle packing' algorithm for that (as others have mentioned).

It will carry on forever, so you'll need to put some code in to decide when to quit, e.g.

- when combined area of placed trees is a certain percentage of area of polygon
- when it takes more than N iterations to find a non-overlapping tree.

According to [Circle Packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) on Wikipedia, the best packing density is achieved with a hexagonal grid. It might be possible to create such a grid using MMQGIS, whose spacing is based on the size of your trees, which I assume are identical. Then placing a tree on each vertex. But then, you have the problem of knowing where to place the grid to maximize the number of trees.

Comment: There is a youtube video explaining packing hexagonal grid in a shape with MMQGIS ["Create Density Maps with a Hexagonal Grid in QGIS"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETk1pbGTen0).

Answer (score 5):

Try this app online svgnest.com/

steps:
1. svg creates a file (as in Figure 1);
2. Go to the link and upload svg;
3. Select with the mouse the container polygon;
4. start

after a number of iterations, you can lock and download the svg file (see Figure 2)

NB: polygon and circles must be in the same file svg

[image: figure 1]

[image: figure 2]

Answer (score 0):

Old but gold, there's a video from 2020 showing how to do it interactively in QGIS. "QGIS how many circles contains a polygon"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zG-5TB5O9og

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).