# Set size of a simple marker Symbol in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am having trouble setting the size of a simple marker. My marker is a circle and I want it to have a radius of 500m. How could I possibly do this? The only options that I see are Millimeters, Points, Pixels, Meter at scale, Map Units, Inches.

Comment: [@Blinxen](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/110188/blinxen), I am just curious, why do you need such big marker size? I think you can achieve it with 500000mm, 19685.039in.

Comment: See this answer, and ensure your map coordinate system is in UTM / metres: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292078/best-site-location-to-plant-trees/292102#292102

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And that´s all you need:

- **`Millimeters, Points, Pixels, Inches`** are **canvas units**, based on e.g. your *screen/printer dimensions*, keeping their
  apparent size independent of zoom/scale;
  If you want your markers to *fill a printed sheet of paper that is 1km in size*, use e.g. `size = 1000000 Millimeter`.
- **`Map units, Meters at Scale`** are **map units**, aware of measures based on the *(scaled) representation of the data and it´s CRS*, keeping it´s size relative to the map scale (note: `Map units` refer to the units of your CRS, so it will be in *degree* for e.g. EPSG:4326);
  If you want to represent your markers with a 500m radius *based on your data*, use e.g. `size = 1000 Meter at Scale`.

Choose wisely...

Comment: Just one last question. How did you calculate the size? How did you know that 500 m equals 1000 meter at scale?

Comment: @Blinxen well...diameter (`Size`) = `2 * r` = `2 * 500m` ...don´t get confused: `1 Meter at scale` will be equal to `1m` *on your map*, calculated by QGIS based on your CRS.